# Dúvida ao retornar string json para evento do FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter, fullcalendar

estou com uma dúvida.
Estou usando o Fullcalendar em um projeto.
Consigo exibir os dados cadastrados no banco normalmente.

O meu problema é no eventClick:
fiz assim:

```
var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate(),
            m = date.getMonth(),
            y = date.getFullYear();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        buttonText: {
            today: 'today',
            month: 'month',
            week: 'week',
            day: 'day'
        },
        eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + 'agenda/get_dados_evento/',
                data: event.id,
                async: true,
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#evento").html(response.id_carro);
                    $("#modal").modal();
                }
            });
        },
        //Random default events
        events: <?php print_r($eventos); ?>,
        editable: true,
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
    });
```

Quando clico em um evento cadastrado no calendário, o event.id é enviado para o controller

```
function get_dados_evento() {

    $id_agenda = $this->input->post('id');
    //$id_agenda = '24';

    $query = $this->model_agenda->get_dados_evento($id_agenda);

    echo json_encode($query->result());
}
```

aqui esta o model:

```
function get_dados_evento($id_agenda){

    $this->db->select(""
            . "agenda.id as id_agenda,"
            . "agenda.id_carro as id_carro_agenda,"
            . "agenda.title as titulo_agenda,"
            . "agenda.start as dt_inicial,"
            . "agenda.end as dt_final,"
            . "agenda.dt_cadastro as data_cadastro_agenda,"
            . "carro.id as id_carro,"
            . "carro.modelo as modelo_carro,"
            . "carro.placa as placa_carro,"
            . "carro.fabricante as fabricante_carro,"
            . "carro.tipo as tipo_carro,"
            . "carro.ano_fabricacao as ano_fabricacao_carro,"
            . "carro.kilometragem as kilometragem_inicial_carro,"
            . "carro.status as status_carro,"
            . "carro.dt_cadastro as data_cadastro_carro");
    $this->db->where('agenda.id', $id_agenda);
    $this->db->join('carro', 'agenda.id_carro = carro.id', 'inner');
    $query = $this->db->get('agenda');

    return $query;
}
```

O meu problema esta na hora de exibir as informações na view... se eu coloco o seguinte codigo no bloco `success:function(response){ console.debug(response);  }` ele imprime o objeto. E na hora que tento exibir `console.debug(response.id_carro);` ele da como indefinido

Comment: Mas porque na hora de repassar pra view não repassa em array? aí só exibe o valor que tá na array()?

Comment: Andre e como faria isso?

Comment: Consegui resolver.

No model agenda, tenho um método que é executado na chamada da classe, ele retorna todos os eventos cadastrados.

O que fiz foi mudar esse método para trazer todas as informações das tabelas relacionadas com o evento (dados do carro, dados do cliente e dados do evento).

Dessa forma já tenho as informações no objeto event do calendario.

Answer (score 1):

Como já resolveu o problema talvez você possa diminuir o código de:

```
eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + 'agenda/get_dados_evento/',
            data: event.id,
            async: true,
            success: function (response) {
                $("#evento").html(response.id_carro);
                $("#modal").modal();
            }
    });
}
```

Para

```
$.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + 'agenda/get_dados_evento/', event.id, function(response){
    $("#evento").html(response.id_carro);
    $("#modal").modal();
});
```